# python script to find the rm process running more than 30 mins on the unix system

Tags: python

I'm looking forward to find the out the any rm (remove command) command running by any user on the Unix systems (viz Linux , Solaris or AIX) which may be running with more than 30 mins. if any capture that and send email to the Admin.

Secondly, Sometime i would require this script just to run on the nfs mounted file-systems only. So far i have created 2 small snippets One is show the all running process on the Server as below:

> 1) script to show the running process :

```
import subprocess
psDig = subprocess.Popen(['ps', 'aux'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
psList = psDig.split('\n')
pfields = len(psList[0].split()) - 1
for row in psList [1:]:
     print row.split(None, pfields)
```

> The above scripts captures the output in the Below format :

```
['smmsp', '24538', '0.0', '0.0', '80656', '2144', '?', 'Ss', 'Apr19', '0:00', 'sendmail: Queue runner@01:00:00 for /var/spool/clientmqueue']
['karn', '27274', '0.0', '0.0', '105072', '784', 'pts/0', 'T', '13:21', '0:00', 'rm -i a fg h j kj']
['root', '27314', '0.0', '0.1', '104508', '4508', '?', 'Ss', '13:21', '0:00', 'sshd: karn [priv]']
['karn', '27317', '0.0', '0.0', '104508', '1856', '?', 'S', '13:21', '0:00', 'sshd: karn@pts/3 ']
['karn', '27318', '0.0', '0.0', '108396', '1980', 'pts/3', 'Ss', '13:21', '0:00', '/bin/bash --login']
['karn', '27376', '0.0', '0.0', '105072', '776', 'pts/3', 'S+', '13:22', '0:00', 'rm -rf a fg h j kj']
['root', '28211', '0.0', '0.1', '191860', '4140', 'pts/6', 'S', 'Apr19', '0:00', 'sudo su - karn']
['root', '28224', '0.0', '0.0', '163708', '1900', 'pts/6', 'S', 'Apr19', '0:00', 'su - karn']
```

So, in the above output i need to Filter only the line which have `rm -i` or `rm -rf`.

> 2) below is the script Just to catch the `NFS` Filesystems only in
>   orfer to run it on the nfs specific mount point.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
import os
def getmount():

    listMount = commands.getoutput('mount | grep nfs')
    mountLines = listMount.split('\n')[1::]
    mountPoints = map(lambda line: line.split()[2], mountLines)
    for listMount in mountPoints:
        print listMount
getmount()
```

> When i run it it, this yields the output like below..

```
bash-4.1$ ./getCurrentmount.py
/home/karn
/grid/common/bin
```

Would appreciate any help or hints on the same.

Comment: Why are there `rm` processes that run more than half an hour? Is the connection to the NFS server unreliable or is the NFS server itself unreliable? If so, would using the `soft` mount option be an alternative?

Comment: @blubberdiblub,  as an Unix admins we are not running that `rm` for so longer but we have identified users in our establishment using `rm` command for their data deletion and sometime they use it mistakenly into the others volumes which creates problem, So, just trying to capture such catastrophic process to identify and kill them timely.